# How to restart spamassassin after failure

Tags: systemd, spamassassin

Periodically, I see the following in syslog:

```
systemd[1]: spamassassin.service: Main process exited, code=exited, status=255/n/a
systemd[1]: spamassassin.service: Unit entered failed state.
systemd[1]: spamassassin.service: Failed with result 'exit-code'.
```

but the service does **not** automatically restart.  It *does* start successfully with:

```
sudo service spamassassin restart
```

Can I configure spamassassin to restart automatically after it fails?

Comment: There is no component to 'restart' SpamAssassin by-default.  You would have to configure some type of monitoring system that'd run to monitor software programs on the system and start them again if they are down.  However, this is actually not going to solve the underlying problem of SpamAssassin occasionally closing or shutting off or crashing. The actual question you *should* be asking **first** is: "Why did SpamAssassin fail to start or fail to shut down gracefully?".  Have you examined why it's dying first?

Comment: You're right. But I was multi-tasking - addressing both the failure cause and the possibility of restart after failure at the same time.

Answer (score 1):

The manpage for systemd.service has the answer. For my particular case, the simplest solution was to add:

```
Restart=always
RestartSec=3
```

to the [Service] section of /lib/systemd/system/spamassassin.service

But there are more sophisticated controls available to limit restarts, should a failure loop occur.